# Relationship between Complexity and Computability

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

*As a response to comments,i'd like to put it in an abstract way,hoping this will make things clearer: f is a well-defined function of countably many inputs:f(a1,...,an,...). For a set of n objects {a1,a2,...,an},we define a series of function f[n] (a1,...,an) = f(a1,...,an,0,0,...), and consider the relationship between algorithm computational complexity of solving f[n] and the computability of f.*

To illustrate my point, please consider a problem (which is a packing problem of discrete mathematics) :given n squares, determine the smallest(inf) area of an enclosing rectangle that will contain all of them without any overlap.

**Suppose** the problem can't be solved in O(1),which means when the input is n squares,then the algorithm complexity A(n) would be more than O(1),which means it's unbounded. If we let n tend to infinity,A(n) will tend to infinity,so the algorithm will "diverge".

Now if we want that given a infinite sequence of squares,there to be a theorem which can,**for any given sequence**,determine the area defined above.(It is a finite number as long as the sum of areas of squares converges.)**Is it true that such a theorem cannot exist,or alternatively,the problem concerning infinite squares is non-computable?**

(If it is computable,how can the complexity of its algorithm diverges when n tends to infinity?)

If the above is true,can we conclude that if a problem whose input concerns infinity is computable,then its corresponding finite problem must be O(1)?

Comment: @hardmath but how can we add two numbers with infinite digit numbers? I see that we can add e with e,but it will take infinite time to know all digits of 2e.so the problem of "determine all digits of 2e",if I understand it right,is non-computable.(by non-computable,I use the word in the sense of undecidable.I think it can be turned into a decision problem: is f(n) equal to 1? where f(n) denote the n-th digit of 2e in decimal representation.)

Comment: $\pi$ is a computable number, meaning that for any number $n$ of decimals that you want, there exists an algorithm that can compute the $n$th digit of $\pi$ in a finite amount of time. However, if we want to compute infinitely many digits of $\pi$, this will take an infinite amount of time. This does not mean, however, that $\pi$ is not computable.

Comment: @mrp yes you're right,I misunderstood it.but regarding the above problem:for any set of {n squares},we have an algorithm,whose complexity is a function of n.but for any set of {coutably many squares},what is its complexity? does such algorithm for the infinity case can even exist? I can't see analogy between this problem and the problem of adding numbers..

Comment: @HunterLiu:  I think you have overwhelmed yourself with trying to leap from consideration of a class of problems with finite data to one that admits an infinite amount of data.  In particular the *definition* of complexity deals with problems whose data is finite.  Your final statement asks, "if a problem whose input concerns infinity is computable, then its corresponding finite problem must be $O(1)$?"  I can spell out in greater detail the analogy with adding numbers, but I think you see computability of $\pi + \sqrt{2}$ does not imply that adding two $n$-digit numbers has complexity $O(1)$.

Comment: @hardmath yes,you're right,but what if we let the function f independent of n? for example,f is 1 if (a+b) contains digit "9",f is 0 if not,now f seems to be non-computable. if you can give an example under the condition that f is independent of n,(with this condition i think it will be a good analog to the situation in square packing problem),i'll accept it as an answer and i'll not say anymore.

Comment: While you may view "function" $f$ as not depending on $n$, surely it must depend on some sort of input, such as (in you original context) an arbitrary sequence of squares subject only to the constraint that the sum of areas is bounded (equiv. forms a convergent sequence).  How would you present this input to an *algorithm*?  I note that you switch when talking about the infinite set of squares from talking about an algorithm to talking about a *theorem*.  This is one of the places I think you have demonstrably confused yourself by leaping from finite data to infinite data.

Comment: @hardmath okay,see my edited post,hope the question is well-defined now.

Comment: I think your Question is fundamentally flawed by trying to proceed on several tracks at once.  The concrete problem you've posed is interesting enough, namely:  Suppose that positive real numbers $x_i$ satisfy a finite sum of squares.  Show that (countably many) squares $x_i\times x_i$ can be packed in a finite square $R\times R$ and give a bound on $R$ related to $\sum x_i^2$.  The rest is (for now) a jumble.  In particular if we deny $f[n]$ is a function of $n$ (although we seem to have a fixed sequence of such functions for any sequence $a_i$ of arguments), what does $O(1)$ mean?

Comment: @hardmath But as I perceive it,there is no such issue. Maybe I should state my thoughts more clearly: the concrete problem(about rectangle packing) is just a background for the question. I agree with you that the wording"every f[n] is not a function of n" is very confusing,so I'll remove this phrase. But its spirit remains in the construction:f(a1,...,an,...),as a function of a1,...,an,... cannot be the n-th digit of (a+b) now. (continues in next comment)

Comment: @hardmath For what $O(M(n))$ means,I think there's no ambiguous:for example,see "Optimal Rectangle Packing" by Korf (2003), https://www.aaai.org/Papers/ICAPS/2003/ICAPS03-029.pdf, page 2,section "Related work",paragraph 2.

Comment: I meant that it is unclear what is being held constant that gets us to a conclusion of $O(1)$, i.e. a "constant" amount of work.  You've invested a lot of effort in trying to frame the Question, so let me try to post in Answer form where I see the gaps that remain.

Comment: @hardmath well, go on please, anyway,you helped me improve it.